# VBA Getting error "Run time error 1004 help"

Tags: excel, vba, office365

Can you see any error with this code ? It have been running flawlessly for a while, but suddently im getting

> 1004 the extract range has a missing or invalid field name

all the time. I cant figure out why. I have modified my Excel very much since last so every now and then it just poops up.

```
Sub FilterMe()
    Dim Num As Range
    Dim Dt As Worksheet, Ft As Worksheet


    Set Dt = Sheets("Data")
    Set Ft = Sheets("FilterData")
    Set Num = Sheets("FilterData").Range("G2")

    Dt.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Ft.Range("O5:R10" & Num), CopyToRange:=Ft.Range("B12:V12"), Unique:=False

 '   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 '   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The debugger shows error at this line:

```
CriteriaRange:=Ft.Range("O5:R10" & Num), CopyToRange:=Ft.Range("B12:V12"), Unique:=False
```

I have tried to change `Num` from `Range`, to `Integer`, to `String` and many other options. But for some reason it wont accept that.

Comment: What is the idea of this - `Ft.Range("O5:R10" & Num)`?

Comment: What is the value of `Num` at the time of error?

Comment: It gets my criteria from those places. My num equals to 6. at that moment.

That is for my advanced filter function using Listbox

Comment: do you realize that for `Num = 6` the `"O5:R10" & Num` will result in `"O5:R106"` and for `Num = 10` it will jump to `"O5:R1010"`? This cannot be correct. Please [edit] your question and explain your overall goal detailed. You are asking the wrong question.

Comment: Good catch sir! It was suppost to be Ft.Range("O5:R" & Num), I have been playing around a little.

This should ofc be jumping between 05:R5 and O5:R10
Ill check if this solved my issue. But tbh i doubt it, because this is why i tried playing around in first place, to fix the issue

Comment: Still getting the Error.

THe problem here is that im getting the same error even if i preset the criteria cell myself manually, it shows error in that line.

O5:R5 and remove &num

This string will basically get my criteria from O5 to RX depandend on what value in G2 is.

Answer (score 0):

I appriciate the time you have put in to help me. I found out what the problem was.

I normally import CSV file that is getting converted to excel database which this program is built on, Somehow somewhere my CSV file got corrupted and the import was changed was made so the headers was different than the Advanced filter once, so when the advanced filter tried to find my values it couldent locate them with the criteria.

I wish you all a nice day and again, thank you

Comment: Since the issue cannot reproduced anymore and is solved in a manner unlikely to help future readers, I voted to close it. • Thx for your feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Ft.range ("O5:R10" & Num) is the wrong usage. Try this code:

> Dt.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
>       CriteriaRange:=Ft.Range("O5:R10," & Num.Address), CopyToRange:=Ft.Range("B12:V12"), Unique:=False

Comment: No `Ft.range("O5:R10" & Num)` works. `Num` is a `Range` object and because of concatenating it to a `String` using `&` its `.Value` is automatically cast into a `String`. You can easily test it.

Comment: that is correct, basically Ft.range("O5:R" & Num) will change from depandend on the value in "Num" So it could be dynamic from O5:R5 and up to O5:R(value of Num) works fine